# Quando entro no sistema Escolher uma empresa para se trabalhar

Tags: c#, winforms

Bom Dia pessoal preciso de uma ajuda de vocês no meu projeto da faculdade estou fazendo um sistema de estoque com 4 camadas, tenho um formulário que é cadastro de empresa onde cadastro empresa usuária que o usuária deseja trabalhar, quando entro no sistema escolho a empresa que o usuário quer trabalhar no momento, como eu faço para que os dados seja daquela empresa, por exemplo empresa A terei os movimentos de estoque da empresa A, quando escolher a empresa B terei os movimentos da empresa B fiz a tela

[image: Tela para selecionar a empresa usuária]

código

Formulário

```
    public frmSelEmpUsuaria()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmSelEmpUsuaria_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarregaEmpresaUsuaria();
    }

    private void CarregaEmpresaUsuaria()
    {
        try
        {
            IList<EmpresaUsuariaDTO> listaEmpresaUsuaria = new List<EmpresaUsuariaDTO>();
            listaEmpresaUsuaria = new EmpresaUsuariaModel().ListaEmpresa();
            dgvEmpresaUsuaria.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgvEmpresaUsuaria.DataSource = listaEmpresaUsuaria;


        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnConfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Não sei o codigo que vai no botão
    }

    private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Camada DAO

```
   public IList<EmpresaUsuariaDTO> ListaEmpresa()
    {


        try
        {
            SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection();
            CON.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.csSistemaEstoque;
            SqlCommand CM = new SqlCommand();
            CM.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            CM.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbEmpresaUsuaria";

            CM.Connection = CON;

            SqlDataReader ER;

            IList<EmpresaUsuariaDTO> ListaEmpresa = new List<EmpresaUsuariaDTO>();
            CON.Open();

            ER = CM.ExecuteReader();

            if (ER.HasRows)
            {
                while (ER.Read())
                {
                    EmpresaUsuariaDTO empresaUsu = new EmpresaUsuariaDTO();

                    empresaUsu.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(ER["cod_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.DataCadastro = Convert.ToDateTime(ER["dtInclusao_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.NomeRazao = Convert.ToString(ER["razao_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.NomeFantasia = Convert.ToString(ER["nomeFant_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.CpfCnpj = Convert.ToString(ER["cnpj_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.RgInscricao = Convert.ToString(ER["inscEst_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Endereco = Convert.ToString(ER["endereco_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Numero = Convert.ToString(ER["numero_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Complemento = Convert.ToString(ER["compl_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Bairro = Convert.ToString(ER["bairro_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Cidade = Convert.ToString(ER["cidade_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Uf = Convert.ToString(ER["uf_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Cep = Convert.ToString(ER["cep_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Telefone = Convert.ToString(ER["tel_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Tel2 = Convert.ToString(ER["tel2_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Email = Convert.ToString(ER["email_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.Site = Convert.ToString(ER["site_emp"]);
                    empresaUsu.EndLogo = Convert.ToString(ER["endLogo_emp"]);


                    ListaEmpresa.Add(empresaUsu);
                }
            }

            return ListaEmpresa;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma força?

Comment: Uma opção é ter um banco de dados para cada empresa. Quando escolher a `empresa A` conecta com o `banco A` o mesmo com a `empresa B`

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira seria criar uma variável global no sistema, tipo GEmp, e quando o usuário logar gravar nessa variável a id/código da empresa.

E ajustar todas as suas sqls/querys pra aceitar como filtro essa id/código da empresa. E todas as suas tabelas também deveram ter a coluna que faz referencia a empresa.

tipo;

```
CM.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbEmpresaUsuaria WHERE idEmpresa=" & GEmp;
```